# Why I can't use wGrid in this view?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am absolutly new in **C#** and **.NET** framework and I have the following problem:

I have this view of a web application:

```
@model DataModel.MaliciousCode.SearchMalicious
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageMobile.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index Andrea</h2>

pageSize : @Model.PageSize

@if (Model.TotalRows == 0)
{
    <h3>Non è stata trovata nessuna vulnerabilità. Modificare i filtri di ricerca.</h3>
}
else
{


    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <p>TABELLA</p>
        @wGrid.GetHtml(
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "MyTable ui-responsive",
            headerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            footerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            rowStyle: "ui-bar-a",
            alternatingRowStyle: "ui-bar-c",
            htmlAttributes: new { data_role = "table", id = "MyWebGrid", data_mode = "reflow" },
            columns: new[]{

                    wGrid.Column ("Title", "Title", canSort : true),  

            })

        @{Html.RenderPartial("Paging", Model);}
    </div>
}
```

My problem is that Visual Studio give me the following errors message related to this view:

> Error 2   The name 'wGrid' does not exist in the current
>   context   c:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\WebPortal\WebPortal\Views\Andrea\Index.cshtml   21  10  WebPortal
>   Error 3   The name 'wGrid' does not exist in the current
>   context   c:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\WebPortal\WebPortal\Views\Andrea\Index.cshtml   31  21  WebPortal

Why? what could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Comment: Well, what's `wGrid` and why would you be able to use it like that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a @using. Another option is to add to the namespaces configuration in web.config in the views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the WebGrid as i've done bellow will work! Just be careful with the with the curly braces! All the best!

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageMobile.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Index Andrea</h2>
pageSize : @Model.PageSize
@if (Model.TotalRows == 0)
{
    <h3>Non è stata trovata nessuna vulnerabilità. Modificare i filtri di ricerca.</h3>
}
else
{

    //Declaring the WebGrid
    @{ WebGrid wGrid = new WebGrid();

    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <p>
            TABELLA</p>
        @wGrid.GetHtml(
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "MyTable ui-responsive",
            headerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            footerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            rowStyle: "ui-bar-a",
            alternatingRowStyle: "ui-bar-c",
            htmlAttributes: new { data_role = "table", id = "MyWebGrid", data_mode = "reflow" },
            columns: new[]{

                    wGrid.Column ("Title", "Title", canSort : true),  

            })
        @{Html.RenderPartial("Paging", Model);}
    </div>

    }
}
```